# In Golang test, how to expect error that WILL be thrown?

Tags: go, testing

I have a test case for which I would like to make a request to a client with the error that will occur in the subject under test.

Like this:

```golang
{
    t.myClient.EXPECT().
        UpdateStatus(thisID, thatID, StatusReport{ 
          Status: 'fail'
          FailureMsg: ???
        }).
        Return(nil).
        Times(1)

    err := t.RunMySubjectUnderTest()

    if t.NoError(err) {
        logOut := t.logBuffer.String()
        t.Contains(logOut, "failed to do")
        t.Contains(logOut, "CLIENT COMM ERROR")
    }
}
```

Subject under test does not return an error but an error occurs during the process and that is being sent with `UpdateStatus`

Error can be many different strings and it has a timestamp in it. It is in a form where there are predictable bits. e.g. `Blah blah timestamp .... CLIENT COMM ERROR .. blah more blah` where `CLIENT COMM ERROR` is a constant.

There are other fields in `StatusReport` as well and I don't want to bypass them with `gomock.Any()`. I would like to expect what should be in `FailureMsg`.

Any suggestion?